# NetSuite Marketing Campaign - Custom Event Fields - Show values in Marketing Templates

Tags: netsuite

I have a scenario where I want to create a dynamically branded marketing template.

The setup:

In my Brand (Class) list i have added several custom fields (ie. Header Image URL, social links etc...). These are stored fields/

In my campaign record I have a Campaign Event custom field where I can select the brand for each campaign event (`custrecord_campaign_event_brand`).

[image]

Last line (actual brands censored for privacy) was used for testing.

However it seems during the merge, there is nothing in these fields even though i can see the data in the event list on the campaign.

Currently using `campaignEvent.custrecord_campaign_event_brand` within the advanced PDF template.

Note, when looking at the Customer Group used to generate the merge, it does not show the value I selected on the campaign event.

Current holding my breath for a NetSuite support ticket as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the NS docs a standard campaign email template cannot reference anything from the campaign except the coupon code.

I don't know if the standard beforeLoad event is emitted for Campaign emails but what I have sometimes had success in adding fields to the standard email templates by using a beforeLoad script on customers that sets values for non-stored custom fields.

Your user event script might need a configured reference for the current campaign but playing with that concept might get you what you need.

Comment: Appreciate that BK. I'll look into the beforeLoad script later today :). NetSuite Support are also investigating, but sounds like it will be an Enhancement Req - which means "don't hold your breath".